# What does the output of this line in pandas dataframe signify?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am learning Pandas DataFrame and came across this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))
```

Now when I use `print(list(df.columns.values))` as suggested on [this page](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pandas-tutorial-dataframe-python), the output is:

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

I am unable to understand the output. What are the values 0,1,2 signifying. Since the height of DataFrame is 2, I suppose the last value 2 is signifying the height. What about 0 and 1?

I apologize if this question is a duplicate. I couldn't find any relevant explanation. If there is any similar question, please mention the link.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If question is what are columns check samples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

#default columns names
print(list(df.columns.values))
[0, 1, 2]

print(list(df.index.values))
[0, 1]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]), columns=list('abc'))
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

#custom columns names
print(list(df.columns.values))
['a', 'b', 'c']

print(list(df.index.values))
[0, 1]
```

You can also check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html):

> The axis labeling information in pandas objects serves many purposes:
>
> Identifies data (i.e. provides metadata) using known indicators, important for analysis, visualization, and interactive console display
> Enables automatic and explicit data alignment
> Allows intuitive getting and setting of subsets of the data set

Comment: That means, it is just printing the names of columns. Is there any better way to print only the names of columns?

Comment: @AyushGoyal - I think it is one of best, similar are `print(df.columns.values.tolist())` or `print(list(df.columns))`

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. That was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

#### What is a data frame?

`df` is a data frame.  Take a step back and take in what that means.  I mean outside what it means from a Pandas perspective.  Though there are many nuances to what different people mean by a data frame, generally, it is a table of data with rows and columns.

#### How do we reference those rows and/or columns?

Consider the example data frame `df`.  I create a 4x4 table with tuples in each cell representing the `(row, column)` position of that cell.  You'll also notice the labels on the rows are `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` and the labels on the columns are `['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[(i, j) for j in range(4)] for i in range(4)],
    list('ABCD'), list('WXYZ')
)

df

        W       X       Y       Z
A  (0, 0)  (0, 1)  (0, 2)  (0, 3)
B  (1, 0)  (1, 1)  (1, 2)  (1, 3)
C  (2, 0)  (2, 1)  (2, 2)  (2, 3)
D  (3, 0)  (3, 1)  (3, 2)  (3, 3)
```

If we wanted to reference by position, the zeroth row and third column is highlighted here.

```
df.style.applymap(lambda x: 'background: #aaf' if x == (0, 3) else '')
```

[image]

We could get at that position with `iloc` (which handles ordinal/positional indexing)

```
df.iloc[0, 3]

(0, 3)
```

What makes Pandas special is that it gives us an alternative way to reference both the rows and/or the columns.  We could reference by the labels using `loc` (which handles label indexing)

```
df.loc['A', 'Z']

(0, 3)
```

I intentionally labeled the rows and columns with letters so as to not confuse label indexing with positional indexing.  In your data frame, you let Pandas give you a default index for both rows and columns and those labels end up just being equivalent to positions when you begin.

#### What is the difference between label and positional indexing?

Consider this modified version of our data frame.  Let's call it `df_`

```
df_ = df.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)

df_

        Z       Y       X       W
A  (0, 3)  (0, 2)  (0, 1)  (0, 0)
B  (1, 3)  (1, 2)  (1, 1)  (1, 0)
C  (2, 3)  (2, 2)  (2, 1)  (2, 0)
D  (3, 3)  (3, 2)  (3, 1)  (3, 0)
```

Notice that the columns are in reverse order.  And when I call the same positional reference as above but on `df_`

```
df_.iloc[0, 3]

(0, 0)
```

I get a different answer because my columns have shifted around and are out of their original position.

However, if I call the same label reference

```
df_.loc['A', 'Z']

(0, 3)
```

I get the same thing.  So label indexing allows me to reference regardless of the order of rows or columns.

### OK!  But what about OP's question?

Pandas stores the data in an attribute `values`

```
df.values

array([[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)],
       [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
       [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)],
       [(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]], dtype=object)
```

The columns labels in an attribute `columns`

```
df.columns

Index(['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], dtype='object')
```

And the row labels in an attribute `index`

```
df.index

Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype='object')
```

It so happens that in OP's sample data frame, the columns were `[0, 1, 2]`